# Creation of a form from the front-office?

Tags: joomla, forms

I'm using the joomla system and I'm looking for a form that can be created from the user interface. that is to say that there will be 3 level. the administrator who will manage all the system, the manager who can create a form from the user interface and collect the information from this form. and finally the user who will enter in the form. is it possible to do this kind of form with the CiviCRM component

Answer (score 2):

There are "profiles" that work with joomla - see https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/joomla/forms/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, does this sentence mean that the user can create their own form from the front office : Navigate to the following URL to test a contact create/sign-up form: /administrator/index2.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/create&reset=1&gid=N
replacing N with the ID of your Profile

Comment: I'm sorry I'm brand new to this extension

Comment: I'm not familiar with joomla but I know it has 2 urls for things. That one looks like a backend url. For the front end it would probably be /index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/create&reset=1&gid=N, e.g. on the public demo this seems to work: https://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/create&gid=1&reset=1